# Coremotion and iPhone orientation by starting App

Tags: swift, orientation, core-motion

I am developing an App with Coremotion and Swift and only for landscape mode. I have the accelerometer (part of Coremotion) working. But when my iPhone orientation is Portrait, the accelerometer is active at the moment.

When I start the app in portrait mode, then it is not possible to stop the accelerometer. Because the app is designed for only landscape and then there is no possibility to test on portrait mode (Swift things de iPhone is always in landscape mode).

Can someone tell me how to make accelerometer only active by starting the app, when the iPhone is only in landscape mode?
Here some code:

```
viewdDidLoad:  
if(motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable){
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates();
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
} 
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time:     TimeInterval):
if let rot = motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude{
           cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(Float(rot.roll +  
 M_PI/2), -Float(rot.yaw), -Float(rot.pitch))
```

Comment: Can you post the code to how you initiate the accelerometer?

Comment: I edited my question with some code.

Comment: Try moving your code into `viewDidAppear()` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: Making sure this has been done. See below image.

[image]

Try :

```
viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft ||  UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight  {
        if(motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable){
            motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates();
            motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;
        } 
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    } // else you could do a notification on orientation left/right
}
```

Comment: It works, but if I have the iPhone in landscape mode after viewDidAppear (start in Portrait mode), I can't start startDeviceNotionUpdates and deviceMotionUpdateInterval. When i have put the same code in func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time:     TimeInterval), the code in viewDidAppear don't work anymore.

Comment: How do you get it to portrait mode if you have that turned off?

Comment: I mean if I have the device (iPhone) in portrait mode, then the scene is in landscape displayed. But when I start the device in portrait and after this I turned the device in landscape mode, then the accelerator must start (startDeviceMotionUpdates and deviceMotionUpdateInterval).

Comment: @JohanKornet Added a photo to the answer. I'm making sure you've actually disabled portrait mode